# Prevent pip from installing some dependencies

Tags: python, pip, aws-lambda

We're developing an *AWS Lambda* function for Alexa skill in Python and using `pip` to install the `ask-sdk` package to our `dist/` directory:

```
pip install -t dist/ ask-sdk
```

The trouble is with the `-t dist/` because `pip` wants to have all the dependencies there, even if they are installed system-wide.

Now, `ask-sdk` has a dependency on `boto3` which pulls in a whole lot of other packages. However the *AWS Lambda* runtime environment provides `boto3` and there is no need to package that and its dependencies with our code. I do have `boto3` installed in the system and `import boto3` works, so I thought `pip` should be happy, but because of `-t dist/` it always installs it.

Can I somehow install just `ask-sdk` and its dependencies that don't exist in the system, e.g. `ask-sdk-core`, but not those that are already installed?

One way is to list all the modules and use `pip --no-deps` but that means a constantly keeping track of the dependencies manually, we would like to avoid that.

Somehow I would like to tell `pip`: if the package is already installed, even if not in `-t dist/` don't put a copy in `dist/`.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: how you deploy lambda function? did you check serverless?

Comment: @ManojJadhav - We use AWS SAM, but deployment is not a problem. We have to package it first, while excluding boto3 and its dependencies.

Answer (score 13):

Although you can't tell pip to "install all dependencies except those required by boto3", you can generate the needed `requirements.txt` by computing the difference between `boto3` and `ask-sdk` from `pip freeze` output (tested with Python 3.6.6):

```
# get boto3 requirements
pip install boto3 -t py_lib.boto3
PYTHONPATH=py_lib.boto3 pip freeze > requirements-boto3.txt

# get ask-sdk requirements
pip install ask-sdk -t py_lib.ask-sdk
PYTHONPATH=py_lib.ask-sdk pip freeze > requirements-ask-sdk.txt

# compute their difference
grep -v -x -f requirements-boto3.txt requirements-ask-sdk.txt > requirements-final.txt

# patch to add one missing dep from boto3
# aws don't have this for some reason
grep urllib3 requirements-boto3.txt >> requirements-final.txt
```

The `requirements-final.txt` contains the following:

```
ask-sdk==1.5.0
ask-sdk-core==1.5.0
ask-sdk-dynamodb-persistence-adapter==1.5.0
ask-sdk-model==1.6.2
ask-sdk-runtime==1.5.0
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.8
requests==2.21.0
urllib3==1.24.1
```

To install the final set of dependencies to a folder:

```
pip install --no-deps -r requirements-final.txt -t py_lib
```

By skipping the `boto3` dependencies, you can save about 45M of data from your python dependencies. The `ask-sdk` dependencies are only about 7.5M (2.1M compressed), allow you to use the build-in lambda code editor if you need to.

Comment: For those finding this answer years later, urllib3 is now a standard part of AWS Python lambdas. You can check if your python verison has it and what other libraries are already pre installed  here: https://insidelambda.com/

Comment: Very clever, thank you. I ran into this problem when installing a project depending on Pytorch on top of its (already massive) Docker image. Nowadays you can even compile your dependencies from `pyproject.toml` using `pip-compile` so they are easy to update.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the option

```
  --no-dependencies
```

To ignore all dependencies.

To exclude specific, you can put it in requirements file and pass it:

```
pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: As I mention in my question above regarding `--no-deps` - we would need to keep track of the dependencies (other than boto3, e.g. `ask-sdk-core`) manually which we would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

`$ pip install -t dist --no-deps ask-sdk`

After the above command I checked out the dist directory content with tree and it had installed only ask-sdk without its dependencies

```
dist/
├── ask_sdk
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __version__.py
│   ├── __version__.pyc
│   ├── standard.py
│   └── standard.pyc
└── ask_sdk-0.1.3.dist-info
    ├── INSTALLER
    ├── METADATA
    ├── RECORD
    ├── WHEEL
    └── top_level.txt
```

Comment: As I mention in my question above regarding `--no-deps` - we would need to keep track of the dependencies (other than boto3, e.g. `ask-sdk-core`) manually which we would like to avoid.