# pip install -r all dependencies from the file except one

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way with single command to install all dependencies in the file except one specified in the command?
I am looking for something like this:
`pip install -r req_file.txt --except unwanted_package`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent pip from installing some dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126116/prevent-pip-from-installing-some-dependencies)

Comment: @Axois Not a duplicate because it is an entirely different functionality of pip (and explicit dependencies vs. transitive dependencies)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do with a shell trick:

```
pip install -r <(grep -v unwanted_package requirements.txt)
```

This is [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

Comment: Doesn't work if a requirement file references another requirement file.
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/fd/requirements.txt'

Answer (score 0):

In my case the process substitution didn't work inside a jenkins container.

Alternative to process substitution could be

```
grep -v "unwanted_package_1|unwanted_package_2" requirements.txt | xargs pip install
```

Comment: This only works if the requirements.txt file is very plain. For example, the command doesn't work if the file contains comments. Unless you more or less write a requirements.txt parser in your command, the process substitution variant is more robust.