# How to install all requirements in requirements.txt EXCEPT a few

Tags: pip, requirements.txt

quick question - I have a big requirements file.  On one system, I have a couple requirements (pytorch, torchvision) which don't install on the a particular machine.  Is there a way I can still use the file to install everything BUT these?  Something like

`pip install -r requirements.txt --except=pytorch,torchvision`

I don't see anything like this in the [pip options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#options) but maybe there's another way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install -r all dependencies from the file except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194887/pip-install-r-all-dependencies-from-the-file-except-one)

Answer (score 4):

There is no way. You have to somehow process the list and exclude packages before passing them to `pip`. Something like

```
pip install `grep -v 'pytorch\|torchvision' requirements.txt`
```

Comment: Just to embellish this answer with an explanation, the -v argument ignores all lines including pytorch and or torchvision

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in Bash, it might be a better idea to use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
pip install -r <(grep -vE '\<pytorch\>|\<torchvision\>' requirements.txt)
```

This way, you don't have to worry about comments etc.
Adding the word boundaries `\<` and `\>` avoids accidentally excluding packages that contain the name of one of the unwanted packages in their names.